# How to access object req inside serializeUser/deserializeUser in PassportJS with Typecript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js

I need to access the req object inside serializeUser and deserializeUser methods. Searching for a solution, I found that the req object is optional inside those methods (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/pull/160#issuecomment-177973983).

My problem is that I am using typescript and the type doesn't come with this req parameter

```
serializeUser<TUser, TID>(fn: (user: TUser, done: (err: any, id?: TID) => void) => void): void;

deserializeUser<TUser, TID>(fn: (id: TID, done: (err: any, user?: TUser) => void) => void): void;
```

, so when I try to use the req parameter inside serializeUser/deserializeUser by just adding the req into the parameters as seen in the github link above the compiler throws an error

> Argument of type '(req: any, id: any, done: any) => void' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type '(id: any, done: (err: any, user?:
>   unknown) => void) => void'.

I'm new to typescript and don't know exactly what I need to modify or create.

Comment: Can you please share the changes you did for adding `req` param and also error you are getting?

Comment: Sure, I added the error message, and the modifications that I made is in the github link, but the modification is to just add the req parameter in the methods.